# BigQuery DML (insert/delete/update) Time Complexity with Partitioning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

What would the partitioning mean for the "time complexity" for updates/inserts? For example, could we get any performance optimization if we have partition, ie we can apply DML operations per multiple partitions vs single table.

Comment: context please?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa included a bit more context on what I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you'd like to know if DML operations can be run on multiple partitions and whether you'll see some performance benefits from this.

According to what it says in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables), dividing a large table into smaller partitions can improve performance. This applies as much to DML operations as regular queries.